# How to specify subtitle palette in MKV-file with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

How could I please define the subtitle palette in an MKV-file?
(Already asked in http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2020-May/048826.html but without any answer.)

I would like to convert videos recorded from TV with DVB-subtitles (such as http://pmrb.free.fr/tmp/ffmpeg-test/sample.mkv) to compressed videos with DVD-subtitles, with nice rendering on my Samsung-TV.

Unfortunately, the result is not very readable: http://pmrb.free.fr/tmp/ffmpeg-test/samsung.jpg

But VLC uses nice colours: http://pmrb.free.fr/tmp/ffmpeg-test/vlc.jpg

I guess, that the Samsung-TV will show better results, when a colour palette is defined in the video file.

I've tried this command:

```
~/tmp/FFmpeg/ffmpeg -i orig-dvbsub.ts -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -c:s dvdsub -palette "0d00ee,ee450d,101010,eaeaea,0ce60b,ec14ed,ebff0b,0d617a,7b7b7b,d1d1d1,7b2a0e,0d950c,0f007b,cf0dec,cfa80c,7c127b" test-output.mkv
```

But it does not work, the rendering on the video players does not change.

TIA for any hints, Peter

Answer (score 0):

the below syntax worked for me :

```
 ffmpeg -probesize 100M -analyzeduration 120M -palette "ffffff,000000,ffffff,00ff00,ffffff,ffffff,ffffff,ffffff,ffffff,ffffff,ffffff,ffffff,ffffff,ffffff,ffffff,ffffff" -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v][1:s]overlay" -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 output.mp4
```

source: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/subtitle_options

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).